# Conditionally show the chart data using angular and echarts

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts

I am trying to show the echart graphs based on the condition. Means if there is data then i have to show the data as well graph but when i have no data then i have to show a simple message in the canvas like "No data". See my below code:
[image]
HTML:

```
    <div *ngIf="PlaybookChart3 != undefined" myECharts [EChartsOptions]="PlaybookChart3" style="height: 300px;">
                </div>
<div *ngIf="PlaybookChart3 === undefined">No Data</div>
```

TS Code:

```
// Pie chart
      this.PlaybookChart3 = {
        title: {
          text: "Category Breakdown",
          x: "left"
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: "item",
          formatter: "{c}",
          textStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 13
          }
        },
        // Enable drag recalculate
        calculable: true,
        series: [
          {
            type: "pie",
            radius: "75%",
            center: ["50%", "50%"],
            selectedMode: "single",
            data: this.ccArray2,
            label: {
              normal: {
                show: true,
                position: "outside"
              },
              emphasis: {
                show: true,
                textStyle: {
                  fontSize: "13"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are trying in the right direction but with different variable.

as I can see you are initializing the `Chart Object` (**`PlaybookChart3`**) so there will no case it's going to be `undefined` that's the reason why you are not getting correct result.

**`ccArray2`** is the data variable you are assigning to the `Chart`, so you need check the data before you are showing the `Chart`

Just change your code something like below,

```
 <div *ngIf="ccArray2.length > 0" myECharts [EChartsOptions]="PlaybookChart3" style="height: 300px;">
                </div>
<div *ngIf="ccArray2.length == 0">No Data</div>
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried with wrong variable. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asserting the existence of your chart object in your *ngIf, another option would be to check your “this.ccArray2” member. Using that, you could determine to show or hide your message and chart elements conditionally as you already are attempting.

I.e: *ngIf=“ccArray2.length” or *ngIf=“!ccArray2.length’